# Swift - PanGestureRecognizer with Hero animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement an animation as explained in this [Tutorial](http://lkzhao.com/2017/02/05/hero-interactive-transition.html) using the Hero-Framework.

At the moment I am at **Step 3** in the Tutorial where the user should be able to drag the View. However that is not working for me. This is my code:

```
// define a small helper function to add two CGPoints
func addCGPoints (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

// handle swqipe down gesture
@objc private func handlePan(gestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  switch panGR.state {
  case .began:
    // begin the transition as normal
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  case .changed:
    // calculate the progress based on how far the user moved
    let translation = panGR.translation(in: nil)
    let progress = translation.y / 2 / view.bounds.height
    Hero.shared.update(progress)

    // update views' position based on the translation
    Hero.shared.apply(modifiers: [.position(addCGPoints(left: translation, right: self.wishlistBackgroundView.center))], to: self.wishlistBackgroundView)
    Hero.shared.apply(modifiers: [.position(addCGPoints(left: translation, right: self.dismissWishlistViewButton.center))], to: self.dismissWishlistViewButton)
    Hero.shared.apply(modifiers: [.position(addCGPoints(left: translation, right: self.menueButton.center))], to: self.menueButton)
  default:
    // end the transition when user ended their touch
    Hero.shared.finish()
  }
}
```

This is how I set up my `ViewController`:

```
view.addSubview(wishlistBackgroundView)
    view.addSubview(dismissWishlistViewButton)
    view.addSubview(menueButton)
    wishlistBackgroundView.addSubview(wishlistView)
    wishlistView.addSubview(wishlistLabel)
    wishlistView.addSubview(wishlistImage)
    wishlistView.addSubview(theTableView.tableView)
    wishlistView.addSubview(addWishButton)
```

Right now the View is not draggable as shown in the tutorial. **Step 1** and **Step 2** work perfectly fine but somehow *updating views position based on translation* does not work for me.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? If there is more context to explain let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding this line:

```
self.wishlistBackgroundView.hero.modifiers = [.fade, .translate(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 800), z: 20)]
```